# Combine multiple rows with same value into one row and add remaining data

Tags: sql-server

I currently have a data as below,

```
timestamp   | tot
-----------------
11          | 1   
11          | 2   
11          | 9
```

I want to combine the **timestamp** into 1 row and sum up all the **tot** values into one for reporting purpose, eg:

```
timestamp   | tot
------------------
11          | 12
```

I have tried *concat*, *concat_ws*, *stuff*, but still no luck on that, is there anyway I can do this or this is impossible to be done?

Comment: Please actually show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement.

> The GROUP BY statement groups rows that have the same values into
>   summary rows

```
 SELECT TimeStamp, SUM(tot) as Tot
 FROM MyTable 
 GROUP BY TimeStamp
```

Answer (score 2):

What about simple aggregation?

```
select timestamp, sum(tot) as tot
from timestamp
group by timestamp;
```